# APA cite multiple authors -- why switch order will affect the effect?

Tags: apacite

I want to cite two paper, which both more than three authors in APA format. As far as I know, when number of the author is more than three, no matter if it is the first time, only the first author will be display. I am using the overleaf platform, and wondering why switch the citation order will change the format.

here is the how I cite the paper,

```
such as A and B
\citep{Petkov2008,Petkov2009} \citep{Petkov2009,Petkov2008}
```

here is how the compiled file show.
such as A and B (Petkov et al., 2008; Petkov, Logothetis, & Obleser, 2009) (Petkov et al.,2008, 2009

here is how those two paper looks in the reference.bib

```
@article{Petkov2008,
author = {Petkov, Christopher and Kayser, Christoph and Steudel, Thomas and Whittingstall, Kevin and Augath, Mark and Logothetis, Nikos},
year = {2008},
month = {04},
pages = {367-74},
title = {A voice region in the monkey brain},
volume = {11},
journal = {Nature neuroscience},
doi = {10.1038/nn2043}
}

@article{Petkov2009,
author = {Petkov, Christopher and Logothetis, Nikos and Obleser, Jonas},
year = {2009},
month = {07},
pages = {419-29},
title = {Where Are the Human Speech and Voice Regions, and Do Other Animals Have Anything Like Them?},
volume = {15},
journal = {The Neuroscientist : a review journal bringing neurobiology, neurology and psychiatry},
doi = {10.1177/1073858408326430}
}
```

thank you all for the time and help:)))

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I'm not sure, whether I get your question correctly, but for me, everything seems to be okay: the 2009 paper has three authors, all are listed, and the 2008 paper has more than three authors, only the first is listed. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: There is a difference between 6th-edition APA style and 7th-edition APA style in the expected behaviour here: For 3 to 6 (I think, maybe its 3 to 5 or 3 to 7) authors 6th-edition APA style wants all authors on first cite and first author + "et al." on subsequent citations of the same work. 7th-edition APA style has the same citation label in all citations. `apacite` implements 6th-ed. APA style. In the LaTeX world 7th-ed. APA style is currently only available with `biblatex-apa`.

Comment: @moewe that's what confused me. thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret the (somewhat fragementary) information you've provided correctly, you're using the `apacite` citation management system -- likely with the option `natbibapa` -- and the `apacite` bibliography style. Do be advised that `apacite` implements the formatting requirements of the *6th edition* of the APA manual.

If your document needs to adhere to the formatting requirements of the current, *7th edition* of the manual, your only viable choice at present is to make the switch to `biblatex`/`biber` and employ to the `apa` style. (There's also the `apa6` style which, I'm sure you can guess, implements the formatting requirements of the 6th ed.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@article{Petkov2008,
author  = {Petkov, Christopher and Kayser, Christoph and Steudel, Thomas 
           and Whittingstall, Kevin and Augath, Mark and Logothetis, Nikos},
year    = {2008},
month   = {04},
pages   = {367--74},
title   = {A voice region in the monkey brain},
volume  = {11},
journal = {Nature Neuroscience},
doi     = {10.1038/nn2043}
}

@article{Petkov2009,
author = {Petkov, Christopher and Logothetis, Nikos and Obleser, Jonas},
year   = {2009},
month  = {07},
pages  = {419--29},
title  = {Where Are the Human Speech and Voice Regions, and 
          Do Other Animals Have Anything Like Them?},
volume = {15},
journa = {The Neuroscientist: A review journal bringing neurobiology, 
           neurology and psychiatry},
doi    = {10.1177/1073858408326430}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=apa,natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{document}
\citep{Petkov2008,Petkov2009}

\citet{Petkov2008,Petkov2009}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry for the missing information. your interpret is totally correct and your pic is exactly what I want. i stored the header.tex , main.tex and references.bib seperately, not sure where I should do the overwrite part. I tried to revise based on your script by adding \usepackage[style=apa,natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib} after \usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} % citation style but then all the reference in paper become ???

Comment: @user226555 - The `apacite` and `biblatex` packages are *mutually incompatible*. Use one or the other, *but not both*.

Comment: thank you, it helps a lot, so far I replace apacite with biblatex, \citet to \textcitea and \citep to \parencite. but I still dont get what is the file content for? now I store the references in References.bib, is it okay?

Comment: @user226555 - If you load the `biblatex` package as `\usepackage[style=apa,natbib]{biblatex}` (as in the answer above), you can keep using `\citet` and `\citep`. (Of course, you don't *have to* use the `natbib` option; it's meant mainly as a convenience.) The `filecontents` environment is used in my answer purely as a convenience to create the sample file `mybib.bib` "on the fly". Naturally, if your real references are stored in a file called `References.bib`, you should specify `\addbibresource{References.bib}`, *not* `\addbibresource{mybib.bib}`.